# Value less than 0 red greater than 0 is green

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this formula to find a cell with a name 'CV_=CVCAL' and from threre offset to another cell. And if the value of the offseted cell is less than 0, then determine the font colour to be red and if it is greater than 0 the font colour is green. However I getting a syntex and complie error. I'm not sure why.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
 If Cells(X, 3).Value = "CV_=CVCAL" Then
   Cells(X, 3).Offset(2, 3).Value > 0 Then
   Cells(X, 3).Offset(2, 3).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
 End If

 If Cells(X, 3).Value = "CV_=CVCAL" Then
   Cells(X, 3).Offset(2, 3).Value < 0 Then
   Cells(X, 3).Offset(2, 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
 End If
```

Comment: You have a 'Then' without an 'If' and 'End If''.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? (I just completed the if-clauses):

```
If Cells(X, 3).Value = "CV_=CVCAL" Then
   If Cells(X, 3).Offset(2, 3).Value > 0 Then
     Cells(X, 3).Offset(2, 3).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
   End If 
   If Cells(X, 3).Offset(2, 3).Value < 0 Then
     Cells(X, 3).Offset(2, 3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
   End If 
End If
```

Just a question: what should happen when the mentioned value is equal to zero?

Comment: Thanks Dominique. Wouldn't the font color remain black if its zero, cause its not specified?

Comment: Nothing would happen, so the colour would remain unchanged.